# Save ImageJ result table to java object or file

Tags: java, imagej

I am writing an imageAnalysis application in java and I use [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/) as library. I would like to ask you if there is a way to save the [results table](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html) as array, json or csv from Java.

Answer (score 0):

As I found out, if you first create a file with File.io library of Java you can then save ResultTable to that file as csv. You can use the [saveAs()](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/measure/ResultsTable.html#saveAs(java.lang.String)) function of ResultTable. Giving the same filepath to that function will populate the file with the results of the table.

Comment: You might want to accept your own answer as the "correct" one, so people can see this question is not being left alone.
On a side-note, you can find the full Javadocs for almost everything ImageJ-related (ImageJ1, ImageJ2, ImgLib2, Fiji, SCIFIO, etc.) on http://javadoc.imagej.net/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am aware of that source, but it is good to mention it for future searches. I am not very happy with my answer and I try to find a cleaner way to solve it. If something come up I will post it.